# Type classes for polymorphic data types in scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism, typeclass, implicit

So I have a polymorphic data type Tree in scala defined as follows

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
final case class Node[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
final case class Branch[A](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

object Tree{

  implicit def eqTree[T]: Eq[Tree[T]] = new Eq[Tree[T]] {
    override def ==(t1: Tree[T], t2: Tree[T]): Boolean = true
  }
}
```

And a type class Eq

```
trait Eq[T]{

  def == (t1: T, t2: T) : Boolean
}
```

And I am trying to do

```
object App1 extends App{

  import Tree._

  def equality[T](t1: T, t2: T)(implicit eq: Eq[T]): Boolean = eq.==(t1, t2)

  println(equality(Node(1), Node(2)))
}
```

However I get the following error

```
Error:(35, 19) could not find implicit value for parameter eq: typeclasses.Eq[typeclasses.Node[Int]]
  println(equality(Node(1), Node(2)))
```

Comment: Where are `T1` and `T2` declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, compiler is trying to find `Eq[Node[Int]]`, and there is no such value in scope. You have defined `Eq[Tree[T]]`.

So basically this is what compiler sees:

```
equality[Node[Int]](Node(1), Node(2))
```

But you actually want this:

```
println(equality[Tree[Int]](Node(1), Node(2)))
```

Comment: Not saying that your observation is wrong, but I don't think his code as is would even compile. notice T1 and T2.

Comment: Another thing to consider is `==`, which is already defined for every object. (Defined is not a good word here, since it's just syntax sugar from `==` to `equals`)

Comment: I am just trying to see if I can get haskell's equivalent of typeclasses working in scala. I know I can use ==

Comment: But on a side note, it is much easier and less painful to get the whole type class thing working in haskell.

Comment: @pedrofula This is pretty ugly but anyway `==` with 2 parameters isn't defined for every object, and hence everything works. I also asumed that it is just a typo and both `T1` and `T2` should have been simply `T`. @Abdul Rahman take a look at simulacrum library that can reduce the pain.

Comment: @pedrofula Yeah T1 and T2 is just a typo. I will correct that in the question.. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulRahman In this case you can just do the usual thing: either define `Eq` to be contravariant `trait Eq1[-T]`, or define `Eq` instances for subclasses: `implicit def eqTree[T, U](implicit ev: U <:< Tree[T]): Eq[U] = new Eq[U] { override def ==(t1: U, t2: U): Boolean = true }`

Comment: @Kolmar neat! Thanks!